# Where can I find a list of all operations possible on lists and maps for Clarity Smart Contracts?

Tags: stack, blockchain, smartcontracts, clarity-lang, stacks-blockchain

Is there a resource for Clarity Smart contracts on Stacks that contains all operations possible on lists and maps?

for instance for lists, I see in the book that you can append but can you also remove elements?
I am not sure whether this is also added in the the Clarity self-guided course book.

If so, please let me know where I can find this.

Answer (score 0):

You can see all Clarity functions listed here: https://docs.stacks.co/docs/clarity/language-functions

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34620451)